# T-SQL equivalent of PL/SQL %TYPE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, plsql

Is there any equivalent to %TYPE in MSSQL2005?

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (ID NUMBER(5));

DECLARE
myVar TEST.ID%TYPE;
BEGIN
................
END;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there isn't any way to inherit the type of a table column when declaring variables in SQL Server 2005 (or 2008, for that matter).

The closest you could get would be to create a user-defined type, and then use it in the table and the code.

Answer (score 2):

It's amazing to me that there isn't an enormous amount of complaint about this. The absence of this capability makes SQL Server code maintainability miserable. What a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: complainers switch to Oracle - and then no need to complain.. :)